Show uniform convergence $(-1)^k \arctan(kx)/ \sqrt{k}$
I have some troubles showing that the following series uniformly converges
$$
\frac{(-1)^k \arctan (kx)}{\sqrt{k}}.
$$
We know that the series converges from Leibniz convergence criteria since
$$
\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{\arctan (kx)}{\sqrt{k}} = \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\infty} = 0.
$$
To show that the series uniformly converge, I perform the following analysis
$$
\bigg | f_k(x) - f(x) \bigg | = \bigg | \frac{(-1)^k \arctan (kx)}{\sqrt{k}} -0 \bigg | = \bigg | \frac{ \arctan (kx)}{\sqrt{k}} \bigg | \leq ?
$$
where
$$
f'_k(x) = \frac{\sqrt{k}}{1+(kx)^2}
$$
which I cannot set to zero $(f'_k(x) = 0)$ to find the supremum, to then use above in the inequality. Sup should also tent to zero when $k \to \infty$.
Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks.
Sincerely, TS

You mean $\leq \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sqrt{k}}$ ?

You are correct. Thanks. How could I miss this.

Since the series satisfies the assumptions for Leibniz test, one has, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$\left|\sum_{k=n}^{+\infty} (-1)^k \dfrac{\arctan(kx)}{\sqrt{k}}  \right| \leq \dfrac{\arctan(nx)}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{n}}$$
The bound in the previous inequality tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to $+\infty$, and does not depend on $x$ ; therefore, the series is uniformly convergent over $\mathbb{R}$.
